# Inner Join and select other columns on that table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a part of my query and I have a union before this query. I want to select more column in table1 under a condition.

```
SELECT  c.ID, c.Name, c.Position, c.Email, c.ContactNumber
FROM table1 c
INNER JOIN table2 a
ON c.ID = (SELECT foreignID FROM table2 WHERE a.Name = 'someName')
WHERE Dept = 'Something' --this will return nothing since in the inner join
                         --the condition returns a single column and it doesn't
                         --satisfy the WHERE Clause
```

I want to select the person that satisfies the ID (which works), including the people with a **Dept** of **Something**.  Is there another way in solving this, or I really need to use UNION for this.  Will this affect the performance of an App, specifically Mobile App?

Comment: Dept is a column of which table? Can't you just use `ON c.ID = a.foreignID and Dept = Something`?

Comment: Dept is from table 1

Answer (score 1):

If I Understood your requirement correctly then Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  c.ID, c.Name, c.Position, c.Email, c.ContactNumber
FROM table1 c
LEFT JOIN table2 a ON c.ID = a.foreignID AND  a.Name = 'someName'
WHERE Dept = 'Something'
```

Comment: uhm,, this returns the column that satisfies the WHERE clause but doesn't return the person in the JOIN part. but thanks, just a bit of twist for this :)

Comment: it's correct but I have to change it to (SELECT foreignID FROM table2 WHERE a.Name = 'someName') and add an OR in WHERE CLAUSE that satisfies c.ID = (SELECT foreignID FROM table2 WHERE a.Name = 'someName')

Comment: you looking for like this `WHERE Dept = 'Something' OR  c.ID = a.foreignID` right??

Comment: yeah I added that, but change the a.foreignID to subquery (SELECT foreignID FROM table2 WHERE a.Name = 'someName')  because the someName can be changed

Comment: If still result not getting then check your table have data which satisfies conditions

Comment: well your query returns data but incomplete, so i just added a condition to it, and changed a bit of your query